# Laravel routing and route parameters

Tags: php, laravel, routes, assets

I have route defined in my route.php file like below:

```
Route::get('{test1}/{test2}/{test3}', function($test1, $test2, $test3) {
    $result = [$test1, $test2, $test3];
    return view('view', compact('result'));
});
```

it works fine in my controller but on the view part when i see it in the browser when i just write something like this in browser:

```
http://localhost/mysitefolder/public/test1/test2/test3
```

it loads the view and pass all the data but it gets all of my assets like my stylesheets, images and scripts from a url like below:

http://localhost/mysitefolder/public/test1/test2/js/jquery.js

why is that happing?
thanks in advance!

Comment: may I see  how you generate the links in your view blade file, are you using `url()` whats is your web server? apache or nginx

Comment: my web server is apache and the shocking part is i just hard coded them i did not use any laravel helper function for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions either use a `/` in the start of your URLs so that relative addressing is not used or use laravel's helper functions `{{ asset('/js/script.js') }}`.

When you do not use '/' in the beginning your url, it is treated as if it was a relative address and current location is added in its start.

Sometimes even '/' won't work if your application is not served on Root level. For example you have your application at `http://localhost/yourapplication` then `/` would refer to your localhost instead of application, that's why best way is to use laravel's helper function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! so could you please tell me why it omits the last part of the url i mean /test3 and loads the assets from http://localhost/mysitefolder/public/test1/test2/js/jquery.js instead of http://localhost/mysitefolder/public/test1/test2/test3/js/jquery.js

Comment: because you don't have any `/` in last part, if you had URL something like `http://localhost/mysitefolder/public/test1/test2/test3/` then its last part would have been included to create relative path.